# ASP.Net MVC : How to add code for client side validation using unobtrusive library for my date validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

i had a requirement as a result user will not be able to enter old days or back days. if enter then validation will occur at server side and proper error message will be thrown to client if date is old or back date.

my server side code as follows but i do not know how to validate the date at client side using unobtrusive library which validate date and stop form submitting to server if dates are found in back or old dates.

### my model code

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class DateValTest
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Back date entry not allowed")]
        public DateTime ? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
```

i use custom attribute called MyDate which extends Validation Attribute class to validate my date to restrict old or back date entry.

### class code for MyDate

```
public class MyDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime _dateJoin = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        if (_dateJoin >= DateTime.Now)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }  
}
```

### here is my sample controller code

```
public class DatValController : Controller
{
    // GET: DatVal
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DateValTest d = new DateValTest();
        return View(d);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateValTest d)
    {
        //DateValTest d = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //d = new DateValTest();
        }
        return View(d);
    }
}
```

### and view code

```
@model AuthTest.Models.DateValTest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

please show me what to add in unobtrusive js code as a result old dates will not be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get client side validation, your attribute must implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to include scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator` For more details on implementing client side validation, refer to [The complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

You attribute would need to be

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TodayOrGreater: ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "The {0} value must be greater than or equal to today's date.";
    private DateTime _MinDate;

    public TodayOrGreater()
    {
        ErrorMessage = _DefaultErrorMessage;
        _MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ....
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "todayorgreater",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

and the scripts

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('todayorgreater', ['mindate'], function (options) {
    options.rules['todayorgreater'] = { mindate: options.params.mindate };
    options.messages['todayorgreater'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("todayorgreater", function (value, element, param) {
    var date = new Date(value);
    var minDate = new Date(param.mindate);
    return date >= minDate;
});
```

Side note: If your wanting to allow todays date, then you want `if (_dateJoin >= DateTime.Today)`, not `if (_dateJoin >= DateTime.Now)`. You will probably also want to include a check for a `null` value.

Comment: what is `ValidationType ` u set `ValidationType = "todayorgreater"` if i give other name like dtChk so what to change in client js code ?

Comment: what is `rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);` ? mindate will be inject at client from server side ?

Comment: `ValidationType = "todayorgreater"` is essentially the name - and if you look at the generated html you will see things like `data-val-todayorgreater` etc. and it needs to match the parameters in the scripts. So if you change it to `dtChk`, then you also need to change the scripts to replace `"todayorgreater"` with `"dtChk"` (4 occasions)

Comment: `rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);` means it also passes the value of `_MinDate` (your server variable) to the view and the html will be like `data-val-todayorgreater-mindate="3/16/2106"`. Again you can name it whatever you like, but if you change it to (say) "todaysdate"` then you also need to modify the script and replace `"mindate"` with `"todaysdate"`

Comment: thanks for reply. i post another similar kind of question for validation. one request that please see and answer if possible. here is my post thread url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033507/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation-end-date-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-st

Comment: I see you have now solved it - note its not really necessary to use `moment` - the issue was `return date >= minDate;` would have throw an error because `minDate` is undefined. You would have need to add `var minDate = new Date(otherProp.val()); before that line of code.

Comment: one request that please have a look at this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043546/asp-net-mvc-regarding-custom-model-property-validation-by-validationattribute   i need some help when i have to work with multiple parameter. would you see the post and share your code and thoughts to solve it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the jquery ui for displaying calendars , you can just set its MinDate attribute to 0, so user cannot select the past dates ,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Comment: no i am not using jquery date picker. i want to do it by custom client side validation by jquery unobtrusive library.

Comment: then you should write a jquery function which validates the date