# ASP.Net MVC Conditional Validation: End date must be greater than or equal to start date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

i could do it server side part. i want if start date is not empty then end date must be equal or greater than start date. server side logic is almost complete but i am bit confuse what to do for client side logic. basically i want to do it by `IClientValidatable` interface.

my server side code as follows

### Model code

```
   public class DateValTest
    {
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DateGreaterThanAttribute(otherPropertyName = "StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End date must be greater than start date")]
        public DateTime?  EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

### attribute code

```
 public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string otherPropertyName;
        public DateGreaterThanAttribute() { }
        public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string otherPropertyName, string errorMessage)
            : base(errorMessage)
        {
            this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
            try
            {
                // Using reflection we can get a reference to the other date property, in this example the project start date
                var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
                var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
                var extensionValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                var datatype = extensionValue.GetType();

                //var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
                if (field == null)
                    return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherPropertyName));
                // Let's check that otherProperty is of type DateTime as we expect it to be
                if ((field.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType && field.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))))
                {
                    DateTime toValidate = (DateTime)value;
                    DateTime referenceProperty = (DateTime)field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                    // if the end date is lower than the start date, than the validationResult will be set to false and return
                    // a properly formatted error message
                    if (toValidate.CompareTo(referenceProperty) < 1)
                    {
                        validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    validationResult = new ValidationResult("An error occurred while validating the property. OtherProperty is not of type DateTime");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do stuff, i.e. log the exception
                // Let it go through the upper levels, something bad happened
                throw ex;
            }

            return validationResult;
        }
    }
```

my concern is how to pass start date textbox name from server side to client side which will add some attribute to end date textbox.

so just help me to construct few server side code for `GetClientValidationRules` function and few code for client side unobtrusive code say for example `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add and $.validator.addMethod` anyone can help me like how to achieve it. thanks

### UPDATE

i try to solve it this way but my client side js is not triggering. here is my revised code.

### Model code

```
public class DateValTest
{
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Back date entry not allowed")]
    [DateGreaterThanAttribute(otherPropertyName = "StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End date must be greater than start date")]
    public DateTime?  EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

### my attribute related code

```
 public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public string otherPropertyName;
        public DateGreaterThanAttribute() { }
        public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string otherPropertyName, string errorMessage)
            : base(errorMessage)
        {
            this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
            try
            {
                // Using reflection we can get a reference to the other date property, in this example the project start date
                var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
                var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
                var extensionValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                var datatype = extensionValue.GetType();

                //var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
                if (field == null)
                    return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherPropertyName));
                // Let's check that otherProperty is of type DateTime as we expect it to be
                if ((field.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType && field.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))))
                {
                    DateTime toValidate = (DateTime)value;
                    DateTime referenceProperty = (DateTime)field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                    // if the end date is lower than the start date, than the validationResult will be set to false and return
                    // a properly formatted error message
                    if (toValidate.CompareTo(referenceProperty) < 1)
                    {
                        validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    validationResult = new ValidationResult("An error occurred while validating the property. OtherProperty is not of type DateTime");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do stuff, i.e. log the exception
                // Let it go through the upper levels, something bad happened
                throw ex;
            }

            return validationResult;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                ValidationType = "isgreater",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", otherPropertyName);
            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

### my js code

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('isgreater', ['otherproperty'], function (options) {
    options.rules['isgreater'] = { isgreater: options.params.otherproperty };
    options.messages['isgreater'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("isgreater", function (value, element, param) {
    alert('pop' + params.otherproperty);
    var otherProp = $('#' + params.otherproperty);
    var date = new Date(value);
    if (otherProp.val() != '')
    {
        return date >= minDate;
    }
    return true;
});
```

My end date textbox html look like as following

```
<input type="date" 
value="03/16/2016" 
name="EndDate" 
id="EndDate" 
data-val-restrictbackdates-mindate="03/16/2016 00:00:00" 
data-val-restrictbackdates="Back date entry not allowed" 

data-val-isgreater-otherproperty="StartDate" 
data-val-isgreater="End date must be greater than start date" 
data-val-date="The field End Date must be a date." 
data-val="true" 
class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line">
```

**the problem is my js code is not firing.....could not capture the area what is the mistake in js code. need some hint or help. thanks**

### I solve it...Updated code here

### Model code

```
public class DateValTest
{
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Back date entry not allowed")]
    [DateGreaterThanAttribute(otherPropertyName = "StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End date must be greater than start date")]
    public DateTime?  EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

### Custom attribute related class code

```
public class MyDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private DateTime _MinDate;

    public MyDateAttribute()
    {
        _MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime _EndDat = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime _CurDate = DateTime.Today;

        int cmp = _EndDat.CompareTo(_CurDate);
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            // date1 is greater means date1 is comes after date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            // date2 is greater means date1 is comes after date1
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            // date1 is same as date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "restrictbackdates",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);
        yield return rule;
    }
}

public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string otherPropertyName;
    public DateGreaterThanAttribute() { }
    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string otherPropertyName, string errorMessage)
        : base(errorMessage)
    {
        this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
        try
        {
            // Using reflection we can get a reference to the other date property, in this example the project start date
            var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
            var extensionValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if(extensionValue==null)
            {
                //validationResult = new ValidationResult("Start Date is empty");
                return validationResult;
            }
            var datatype = extensionValue.GetType();

            //var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
            if (field == null)
                return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherPropertyName));
            // Let's check that otherProperty is of type DateTime as we expect it to be
            if ((field.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType && field.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))))
            {
                DateTime toValidate = (DateTime)value;
                DateTime referenceProperty = (DateTime)field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                // if the end date is lower than the start date, than the validationResult will be set to false and return
                // a properly formatted error message
                if (toValidate.CompareTo(referenceProperty) < 1)
                {
                    validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                validationResult = new ValidationResult("An error occurred while validating the property. OtherProperty is not of type DateTime");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Do stuff, i.e. log the exception
            // Let it go through the upper levels, something bad happened
            throw ex;
        }

        return validationResult;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "isgreater",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", otherPropertyName);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

### View code with js

```
@model AuthTest.Models.DateValTest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('restrictbackdates', ['mindate'], function (options) {
        options.rules['restrictbackdates'] = { mindate: options.params.mindate };
        options.messages['restrictbackdates'] = options.message;
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("restrictbackdates", function (value, element, param) {
        var date = new Date(value);
        var minDate = new Date(param.mindate);
        return date >= minDate;
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('isgreater', ['otherproperty'], function (options) {
        options.rules['isgreater'] = { otherproperty: options.params.otherproperty };
        options.messages['isgreater'] = options.message;
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("isgreater", function (value, element, param) {
        var otherProp = $('#' + param.otherproperty);
        if (otherProp.val() != '') {
            var StartDate = new Date(moment(otherProp.val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

            var Enddate = new Date(value);
            if (StartDate != '') {
                return Enddate >= StartDate;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
</script>

}
```

Comment: The final approach seems to be based on https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting it right - then you need to add validation on End Date based on Start Date i.e., Depending value. 
It can be done very easily using Foolproof.js where there are various attributes like RequiredIf, RequiredIfRegexMatch etc. You can also write you customized code overridding the default attributes in the same manner like we do for MVC attributes. 
One example:

```
using Foolproof;

public class MustBeTrueIfAttribute : RequiredIfAttribute
{
    static MustBeTrueIfAttribute()
    {
        Register.Attribute(typeof(MustBeTrueIfAttribute));
    }

    public MustBeTrueIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object dependentValue)
        : base(dependentProperty, dependentValue)
    {
    }

    public MustBeTrueIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, Operator @operator, object dependentValue)
        : base(dependentProperty, @operator, dependentValue)
    {
    }


    public override string ClientTypeName => "mustbetrueif";

    public override bool IsValid(object value, object dependentValue, object container)
    {
        return !this.Metadata.IsValid(dependentValue, this.DependentValue) || (value != null && (bool)value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a very powerful and customizable js library. Refer: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

for client side validation , if you are using jquery ui (datepicker) all you need to do is

```
   $(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
        }
    });
});
```

Source :http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-DatePicker-Start-Date-should-be-less-than-End-date-validation.aspx

Comment: i am looking for asp.net mvc custom validation not jquery.

Comment: If u'r open for adding new library in your code - Foolproof.js would prove very helpful. Not only in the current scenarion your referring but a wide range of attributes and can be easily customized.